# Mini cart not show product when add product for first time Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, addtocart, mini-cart

I am using Ultimo Infortis theme. I am facing issue in adding product to mini cart. First time when i click on Add to Cart button, it do not show product in mini cart but on cart page it show added product. If i again add product to cart then mini cart show added products lists.

This is happening form the first day. I disabled magento cache but still the issue is there.

Can anyone suggest me how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is magento2's default bug

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5377

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4170

for the temporary solution, you can refresh mini cart in all page for that you can use below code.

**default.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="refresh.minicart" template="{vendor}_{module}::refreshMinicart.phtml"  />
    </referenceContainer>
  </body>
</page>
```

**refreshMinicart.phtml**

```
<script>
  require([
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
  ], function (customerData) {
    var sections = ['cart'];
    customerData.invalidate(sections);
  });
</script>
```

**EDIT**

`/app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

`/app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Theme/templates/refreshMinicart.phtml`

or if you have created module then you can paste at

`app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/`

`app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/`

Comment: Thanks for your response.. Can you tell the path of files where i should place this code

Comment: /app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

/app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Magento_Theme/templates/refreshMinicart.phtml

or if you have created module then you can paste at app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout, app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates

Comment: i don't have templates folder in my theme.. I placed xml code in /app/design/frontend/Infortis/base/Magento_Theme/layout but for script changes i dont have template folder inside Magento_theme.. In Magento_theme i have layout,page_layout, web folders not template and inside these folder i don't have refreshminicart.phtml.. I checked for module but ib app/code there is no vendor folder

Comment: Thanks for your big help.. The links you provided works for me.. Thanks alot.. :)

Comment: you have to create `refreshminicart.phtml` file and `vendor` is not a folder its a just a vendor of any module e.g. app/code/Folder/Module/ .. `Folder` is your **vendor** and `Module` is **Module**.

Comment: i would like to refresh the mini cart from custom module, could you please confirm whether we have create default.xml in our custom module?

Comment: Yes, you can create anywhere in your module or in your theme layout folder.

Comment: @chirag How can i add this on custom module i need to know is there any change will occur on default.xml how it will look like in custom module

Comment: @Amith same way. app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/

app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/

Comment: @ chirag when i tried to paste this code on my custom module with my module name i got an error that "object not created"

Comment: @Amith please ask question with your code. i will check and answer you.

Comment: @chirag https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194777/update-minicart-programatically-in-magento-2

Comment: @ chirag did you check the question?