# Add Products through Custom module in magento2

Tags: magento2, module, multiple-add-to-cart

I'm trying to add number of products to cart at a time using custom module

here is my module code

> app/code/Multiple/Addtocart/Controller/Index/Cartadd.php

```
<?php
    namespace Multiple\Addtocart\Controller\Index;    
    use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
    use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
    use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart as CustomerCart;
class Cartadd extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $checkoutSession;
    protected $formKey;
    protected $request;
    protected $cart;

  public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
     CustomerCart $cart,
    PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    array $data = []) 
    { 
        $this->formKey = $formKey;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
         $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }


  public function execute()
  {
    $pid=array();
    $pid=$_POST['data'];
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    for($i=0;$i<count($pid);$i++){
        $product_id=$pid[$i]['id'];
        $product_qty=$pid[$i]['qty'];
        $_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
        echo $_product->getName()."<br>";
        $params = array(
                    'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                    'product' =>$product_id, //product Id
                    'qty'   =>$product_qty //quantity of product                
                    );              

                  //$_product = $this->product->load($tradeProductId);
                  //$this->cart->truncate();
                  $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
                  $this->cart->save();
                  $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Item has been successfully added to cart.'));   
    }   

  }
}
```

> app/code/Multiple/Addtocart/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="add_prodct_addtocart_after">
        <observer name="Multiple_Addtocart" instance="Multiple\Addtocart\Observer\CustomPrice" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> app/code/Multiple/Addtocart/Observer/CustomPrice.php

```
<?php
    namespace Multiple\Addtocart\Observer;
    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
    use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
    class CustomPrice implements ObserverInterface
    {

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) 
    {
            $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP.'/var/log/multiproduct.log');
            $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
            $logger->addWriter($writer);
}
}
```

Comment: hi @amith instead of Class Display keep Class Cartadd

Comment: @Nagaraju Kasa i have changed but still 404 page showing

Comment: hi @amith just follow the steps below and get back with u r comments thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Step 1:- Template File path:-
>   /app/code/Multiple/Addtocart/view/frontend/templates/addtocart_index_index.phtml

```
<form name="paytrade-orders-list" id="paytrade-orders-list" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('addtocart/index/cartadd');?>" method="post" >

<div class="saveandmore">
<button type="submit" class="buyersave"><?php echo _('Pay Now');?></button>
<label><span><?php echo _('Select all');?> </span><input type="checkbox" id="select_all" /></label>
</div>

</form>
```

Step2:-

> /app/code/Multiple/Addtocart/Controller/Index/Cartadd.php

```
<?php
    namespace Multiple\Addtocart\Controller\Index;    
    use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
    use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
class Cartadd extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $formKey;
    protected $request;

  public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
    PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    array $data = []) 
    { 
        $this->formKey = $formKey;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }


  public function execute()
  {
    echo 'Hello World';   

  }
}
```

**Step 3:-** Use di compile and clear cache and full page cache when ever u change the __construct()

as well as use magento2  log whether u r controller is calling or not

Comment: But here /app/code/Multiple/Addtocart/view/frontend/templates/addtocart_index_index.phtml i dont need this i have alredy added this select box in my list.phtml file and from there i have added a button while clicking that button all selected products id will get in this file Cartdadd.php using ajax

Comment: ok in your ajax url use <?php echo $this->getUrl('addtocart/index/cartadd');?> (or) <?php echo $block->getUrl('addtocart/index/cartadd');?>

Comment: here addtocart is a module name and index is a controller and action file is cartadd.php

Comment: now i can access the module can we go to next step?

Comment: ok @amith go head and in the controller keep the hard coded data before implementing dynamically for working or not oke?

Comment: please confirm whether u r able to add product to cart or not?

Comment: Let me know what u did mistake (coding) ?

Comment: as per ur suggestion  i have try to save the product with ststic value but i'm getting "Undefined property error on this line $this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);

Comment: Please check my updated code for cartadd.php

Comment: hi amith i think u have missed the marked lines please find the screenshot http://prntscr.com/go8wnb

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66000/discussion-between-amith-and-nagaraju-kasa).

Comment: @ Nagaraju Kasa is there any mistakes from my side?

Comment: after did the changes in the construct () whether u did compile if not do the compile

Comment: May be u r doing inserting wrong dependency  check it once and update me thanks  http://prntscr.com/go8wnb

Comment: i didn't get "May be u r doing inserting wrong dependency" we have added the required files there then what will be the reason for the error

Comment: if i'm inserting wrong dependency which file i need to add their i don't have any idea about that

Comment: finally its getting worked now the products add in cart but here i have small issue in cart the price of first product is only showing other product price is 0

Comment: For product price use observer concept using controller unble to add price. Their is add_prodct_addtocart after observe make use of it and get back with u r comments thanks

Comment: @ Nagaraju Kasa  i did't get it can you explain it please

Comment: Do you have any sample codes currently in cart page whwn i addmore than one product the first product price is showing there and the remaingin price is set as 0 but the total cart price is correct

Comment: @ Nagaraju Kasa  please check my updated code its not getting worked can you check it please and in the observer how can i add price i dont want the custom price i need the original price of the product

Comment: i have fixed every issue except mini cart now i got every thing worked but the issue is in mini cart the item show their but the price and quantity not updating (the issue only in mini cart)

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160203/mini-cart-not-show-product-when-add-product-for-first-time-magento-2-1

Comment: https://webkul.com/blog/update-mini-cart-magento2/

Comment: please have a look on this http://dealer.xtrememats.desirewebbies.com/products.html

Comment: @ Nagaraju Kasa  can you answe for this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/197084/how-to-show-tier-price-in-magento-2-catalog-page