# How to Show Tier Price in Magento 2 Catalog Page

Tags: magento-2.1, catalog, tierprice

I have setup a tier price for my Magento 2 product and I can see the tier price on product details page like below screen shot.

[image]

I need to show the same **"Buy 3 for $0.00 each and save 100%"** in my catalog page also. Is there any way to show like this? Can anyone help me?

Comment: does catalog page means product list page?

Comment: @ Rita Jose yes it is

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add tier prices from admin panel.

> Navigate to Admin Panel > Catalog > Product > Add/Edit Product >
>   Advance Pricing (below price input box) > Tier Price > Add

Magento shows tier price in product view page by default.
If you want to show tier price in product list page then put below code in your **list.phtml** file where you want to show tier price.

```
if($_product->getTierPrice()){
    $tier_price = $_product->getTierPrice();
    foreach ($tier_price as $key => $value) {
        $qty = (int)$value['price_qty'];
        $price = $value['price'];
        $formattedPrice = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data')->currency(number_format($price, 2), true, false);
        $savePercentageFormat = ceil(100 - ( (100 / $_product->getPrice())* $value['price']) ) ."%";

        echo "Buy $qty for ".$formattedPrice." each and save ".$savePercentageFormat;
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: i have alredy added it that's why it showing in product page just check the image the problem is its not showing on catalog page

Comment: check my updated answer.

Comment: @ Dinesh Yadav hey great answer working fine thank you.....

Answer (score 1):

```
$formattedPrice = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data')->currency($price,true,false);
```

This works better.. The previous if you have prices in the thousands reformatted 7,490.00 to 7.00

Answer (score 0):

unfortunally the code does not work for me in list.phml. no products are shown if I put the code to < ? php ... ? >
and if I use
< ? =  ... ? > it gives me a blank page. Can you please specify how to put the code to list.phtml?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, the function works only on simple products. Would it be possible to make it work in configurables?

I figured out that if you set a tier price higher than the regular price, it will show the regular price anyway. If this is the "normal" functionality, always show the lowest price if it's possible.

But I need to change this functionality, for example set a regular price of $ 10 for a product and $ 15 for a customer group X.

How can I do it?