# Update Minicart programatically in magento 2

Tags: magento2, upgrade, mini-cart

I have create problematically adding number of products at a time in Magento 2 cart and there I can one see one first product in mini cart other products are also in mini-cart but not showing the count and price

here is the code that i tried to update mini-cart

> app/code/Multiple/Addtocart/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Multiple_Addtocart" setup_version="2.1.1">
   </module>
   </config>
```

> app/code/Multiple/Addtocart/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="refresh.minicart" template="Multiple_Addtocart::refreshMinicart.phtml"  />
    </referenceContainer>
  </body>
</page>
```

> app/code/Multiple/Addtocart/view/frontend/templates/refreshMinicart.phtml

```
<?php
?>
<script>
  require([
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
  ], function (customerData) {
    var sections = ['cart'];
    customerData.invalidate(sections);
  });
</script>
```

But here i'm getting object not created error

[image]

Comment: have you added `Magento_Customer` in your ***module.xml*** as sequence?

Comment: @ chirag no how can i add this? checkout my updated code i have added my module.xml file

Comment: check my answer

Comment: @ chirag  got any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Please add `sections.xml` file under

> etc -> fronted -> sections.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="checkout/cart/add">
       <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
```

Comment: i have tried this code but no change please check my updated question with image

Answer (score 0):

Have you add `Magento_Customer` in your ***vendor/module/etc/module.xml***?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
   <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Customer"/>  
    </sequence>
  </module>
</config>
```

Comment: in my question i have added the code app/code/Multiple/Addtocart/view/frontend/templates/refreshMinicart.phtml is there any change for this also is this require now?

Comment: no changes, that is also required. is it working?

Comment: its not getting worked yet i dont know why my minicart not getting updated but in cart everything is ok is there any other way do you have any idea to update minicart or relod it the mini cart will only update when we change quantity or delete anything from minicart

Comment: can you share your site url?

Comment: @ chirag dealer.xtrememats.desirewebbies.com/products.html

Comment: @ chirag  can you answer for this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/197084/how-to-show-tier-price-in-magento-2-catalog-page