# Magento 2: Minicart is not updated for certain storeviews when adding product for the first time

Tags: multistore, magento2.2.2, mini-cart

II have multiple websites and storeviews in my Magento 2.2.2 installation.

I have experienced a weird issue, that for some storeviews, when adding a product to the shopping cart for the first time, the mini cart is not updated, and still showing empty cart (see screenshot).

[image]

But when I add the product again, then Minicart is updated, but the **Quantity** besides the minicart is showing 1, even I can see both products - the previous one, and the new one.

All my websites are using the **same templates** and javascripts / html. It's only the currency and language that are different.

I have tried the solution from this post [Mini cart not show product when add product for first time Magento 2.1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160203/mini-cart-not-show-product-when-add-product-for-first-time-magento-2-1?rq=1) but didn't help.

I'm using Magento 2.2.2